# How to set parameters' sum to 1 in constrained optimization

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

Here's the code (I'm sorry if it's so long, but it was the first example I had); I'm using the CVaR example from `CreditMetrics` package by A. Wittmann and `DEoptim` solver to optimize:

```
library(CreditMetrics)
library(DEoptim)

N <- 3
n <- 100000
r <- 0.003
ead <- rep(1/N,N)
rc <- c("AAA", "AA", "A", "BBB", "BB", "B", "CCC", "D")
lgd <- 0.99
rating <- c("BBB", "AA", "B")   
firmnames <- c("firm 1", "firm 2", "firm 3")
alpha <- 0.99

# correlation matrix
rho <- matrix(c(  1, 0.4, 0.6,
                  0.4,   1, 0.5,
                  0.6, 0.5,   1), 3, 3, dimnames = list(firmnames, firmnames),
              byrow = TRUE)

# one year empirical migration matrix from standard&poors website
rc <- c("AAA", "AA", "A", "BBB", "BB", "B", "CCC", "D")
M <- matrix(c(90.81,  8.33,  0.68,  0.06,  0.08,  0.02,  0.01,   0.01,
              0.70, 90.65,  7.79,  0.64,  0.06,  0.13,  0.02,   0.01,
              0.09,  2.27, 91.05,  5.52,  0.74,  0.26,  0.01,   0.06,
              0.02,  0.33,  5.95, 85.93,  5.30,  1.17,  1.12,   0.18,
              0.03,  0.14,  0.67,  7.73, 80.53,  8.84,  1.00,   1.06,
              0.01,  0.11,  0.24,  0.43,  6.48, 83.46,  4.07,   5.20,
              0.21,     0,  0.22,  1.30,  2.38, 11.24, 64.86,  19.79,
              0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0, 100
)/100, 8, 8, dimnames = list(rc, rc), byrow = TRUE)

cm.CVaR(M, lgd, ead, N, n, r, rho, alpha, rating)

y <- cm.cs(M, lgd)[which(names(cm.cs(M, lgd)) == rating)]
```

Now I write my function...

```
fun <- function(w) {
  # ... 
  - (t(w) %*% y - r) / cm.CVaR(M, lgd, ead = w, N, n, r, 
                           rho, alpha, rating)
}
```

...and I want to optimize it:

```
DEoptim(fn = fun, lower = rep(0, N), upper = rep(1, N), 
        control = DEoptim.control())
```

Can you tell me what do I have to insert in `# ...` to make `sum(w) = 1` during optimization?

Below I show you optimization results according to flodel's tips:

```
# The first trick is to include B as large number to force the algorithm to put sum(w) = 1

fun <- function(w) {
  - (t(w) %*% y - r) / cm.CVaR(M, lgd, ead = w, N, n, r, rho, alpha, rating) + 
    abs(10000 * (sum(w) - 1))
}

DEoptim(fn = fun, lower = rep(0, N), upper = rep(1, N), 
        control = DEoptim.control())

$optim$bestval
[1] -0.05326055

$optim$bestmem
par1        par2        par3 
0.005046258 0.000201286 0.994752456

parsB <- c(0.005046258, 0.000201286, 0.994752456)

> fun(parsB)
            [,1]
[1,] -0.05326089
```

...and...

As you can see, the first trick works better in that he finds a results which is smaller than the second one. Unfortunately it seems he takes longer.

```
# The second trick needs you use w <- w / sum(w) in the function itself

fun <- function(w) {
  w <- w / sum(w)
  - (t(w) %*% y - r) / cm.CVaR(M, lgd, ead = w, N, n, r, rho, alpha, rating) #+ 
    #abs(10000 * (sum(w) - 1))
}

DEoptim(fn = fun, lower = rep(0, N), upper = rep(1, N), 
        control = DEoptim.control())

$optim$bestval
[1] -0.0532794

$optim$bestmem
par1         par2         par3 
1.306302e-15 2.586823e-15 9.307001e-01

parsC <- c(1.306302e-15, 2.586823e-15, 9.307001e-01)
parC <- parsC / sum(parsC)

> fun(parC)
           [,1]
[1,] -0.0532794
```

Any comment?

Should I increase the number of iterations because of a "too-stochastic" to-be-optimized-function?

Comment: In the code for the "second trick" above, you forgot to add `w <- w / sum(w)` in the body of `fun`. Can you please update your code and results?

Comment: Thank you, I've just updated. What would the best method be according to these results?

Comment: Thanks. Note that I never suggested what is still labelled as "second trick": it is wrong and you should delete it. What I suggested is what are currently labelled as "first trick" and "third trick". I suggested yet another method: to use `w <- c(w, 1-sum(w))` in the body of `fun` and outside, have you tried that as well? I think this last method might be a little more robust and faster.

Comment: You're right, I've deleted the wrong one. I forgot that, having set variables' upper bound to 1, to not insert `w <- w / sum(w)` in the function body would have given me wrong results.

Comment: Regarding `w <- c(w, 1-sum(w))`, it returns me an error of array non-comformable arguments in `t(w) %*% y`.

Comment: For that last one, you have one fewer variable, so you need to set your bounds to `lower = rep(0, N-1)` and `upper = rep(1, N-1)`.

Comment: Is it possible that, according to this last method, the last variable (the one obatined by `1 - sum(w)`) is negative? This would go against my boundaries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
w <- w / sum(w)
```

and if `DEoptim` gives you an optimal solution `w*` such that `sum(w*) != 1` then  `w*/sum(w*)` should be your optimal solution.

Another approach is to solve over all your variables but one. We know the value of the last variable must be `1 - sum(w)` so in the body of the function, have:

```
w <- c(w, 1-sum(w))
```

and do the same to the optimal solution returned by `DEoptim`: `w* <- c(w*, 1-sum(w*))`

Both solutions require that you re-formulate your problem into an unconstrained (not counting for variable bounds) optimization so `DEoptim` can be used; which forces you to do a little extra work outside of `DEoptim` to recover the solution to the original problem.

In reply to your comment, if you want `DEoptim` to give you the correct answer right away (i.e. without the need for a post-transformation), you could also try to include a penalty cost to your objective function: for example add `B * abs(sum(w)-1)` where `B` is some arbitrary large number so `sum(w)` will be forced to `1`.

Comment: Thank you, flodel, that was the solution I was used to. But I would like the opitmization ouput already sums to 1. Few months ago I remember of a function example which had this constraint embedded in the function itself, but I'm not able to recover it :(

Comment: Thank you for your suggestment, flodel. Unfortunately I'm not skilled in constrained optimization, then I'm going to show you what I obtained using both your suggestments. The «large `B` trick» was slower in convergence: in fact, it tried to minimize `B` then it went on the first part of my equation; the normalization to 1 of parameters allowed faster convergence but, after normalization, I obatined sub-optimal solution. I'm going to edit my question in order to show you my codes...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a penalty for any deviation from one.
Add to your minimizing problem the term `+(sum(weights) - 1)^2 * 1e10`. You should see that this huge penalty will force the weights to sum to 1!

Answer (score 0):

With the trick you applied:

```
fun <- function(w) {
  w <- w / sum(w)
  - (t(w) %*% y - r) / cm.CVaR(M, lgd, ead = w, N, n, r, rho, alpha, rating) #+ 
    #abs(10000 * (sum(w) - 1))
}
```

Why would you not use optim in this case? I think it will be much faster.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Put questions and requests for clarification in the comments section, not in the answers section.