# Constrained optimization of a vector

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I have a (non-symmetric) probability matrix, and an observed vector of integer outcomes. I would like to find a vector that maximises the probability of the outcomes, given the transition matrix. Simply, I am trying to estimate a distribution of particles at sea given their ultimate distribution on land, and a matrix of probabilities of a particle released from a given point in the ocean ending up at a given point on the land.

The vector that I want to find is subject to the constraint that all components must be between 0-1, and the sum of the components must equal 1. I am trying to figure out the best optimisation approach for the problem.

My transition matrix and data set are quite large, but I have created a smaller one here:

I used a simulated known at- sea distribution of 
`msim<-c(.3,.2,.1,.3,.1,0)` and a simulated probability matrix (t) to come up with an estimated coastal matrix (Datasim2), as follows:

```
t<-matrix (c(0,.1,.1,.1,.1,.2,0,.1,0,0,.3,0,0,0,0,.4,.1,.3,0,.1,0,.1,.4,0,0,0,.1,0,.1,.1),
nrow=5,ncol=6, byrow=T)
rownames(t)<-c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5") ### locations on land
colnames(t)<-c("S1","S2","S3","S4","S5","S6") ### locations at sea

Datasim<-as.numeric (round((t %*% msim)*500))

Datasim2<-c(rep("C1",95), rep("C2",35), rep("C3",90),rep("C4",15),rep("C5",30))
M <-c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1) ## starting M
```

I started with a straightforward function as follows:

```
EstimateSource3<-function(M,Data,T){

EstEndProbsall<-M%*%T
  TotalLkhd<-rep(NA, times=dim(Data)[1])

  for (j in 1:dim(Data)[1]){

ObsEstEndLkhd<-0
    ObsEstEndLkhd<-1-EstEndProbsall[1,]  ## likelihood of particle NOT ending up at locations other than the location of interest

      IndexC<-which(colnames(EstEndProbsall)==Data$LocationCode[j], arr.ind=T) ## likelihood of ending up at location of interest

      ObsEstEndLkhd[IndexC]<-EstEndProbsall[IndexC]

      #Total likelihood
      TotalLkhd[j]<-sum(log(ObsEstEndLkhd)) 
  }

  SumTotalLkhd<-sum(TotalLkhd)


  return(SumTotalLkhd)
}

DistributionEstimate <- optim(par = M, fn = EstimateSource3, Data = Datasim2, T=t, 
control = list(fnscale = -1, trace=5, maxit=500), lower = 0, upper = 1)
```

To constrain the sum to 1, I tried using a few of the suggestions posted here:[How to set parameters' sum to 1 in constrained optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655217/how-to-set-parameters-sum-to-1-in-constrained-optimization)

e.g. adding `M<-M/sum(M)` or `SumTotalLkhd<-SumTotalLkhd-(10*pwr)` to the body of the function, but neither yielded anything like msim, and in fact, the 2nd solution came up with the error “L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'”

I thought perhaps the quadprog package might be of some help, but I don’t think I have a symmetric positive definite matrix…

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please explain the math of your problem.  You know the transition matrix T and distribution on land L and you are looking for most likely distribution at sea S?

Is the relationship something like L' = S' T?  This looks like a matrix equation to me, nothing to optimize here.

You ask for "most likely" solution.  How do you introduce randomness into the process?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. Yes, we know the transition matrix (T) and land distribution (Datasim2), and looking for sea distribution (M). I am attempting to solve for this using matrix equations, but am running into problems trying to get a pseudoinverse of T. I tried `invT <- ginv(T)` but for some reason this does not work;  (invT %*% T does not yield an identity matrix. I cannot figure out why! Note that I have transposed the transition matrix in order for the matrix equation to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

What about that: Let D = distribution at land, M = at sea, T the transition matrix.  You know D, T, you want to calculate M.  You have

D' = M' T

hence D' T' = M' (T T')

and accordingly D'T'(T T')^(-1) = M'

Basically you solve it as when doing linear regression (seems SO does not support math notation: ' is transpose, ^(-1) is ordinary matrix inverse.)

Alternatively, D may be counts of particles, and now you can ask questions like: what is the most likely distribution of particles at sea.  That needs a different approach though.

Comment: Yes, D is indeed counts of particles (turtles, to be exact!). And that's exactly what I'm looking for, the most likely distribution of turtles at sea. As for solving by multiplying by T' and (TT')^(-1) I keep receiving the error "system is computationally singular", so (TT') is apparently singular. Even when I re-generate it using random numbers. I suppose that is potentially why ginv did not work on the previous example.

Comment: In the non-simplified data set, M is much larger than D. There are 1315 points at sea (M) and 114 on land (D). Is this problem still solveable using matrix equations?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have never done such models but think along the following lines.  Let M be of length 3 and D of length 2, and T is hence 3x2.  We know T and we observe D_1 particles at location 1 and D_2 particles at location 2.

What is the likelihood that you observe one particle at location D_1?  It is *Pr(D = 1) = M_1 T_11 + M_2 T_21 + M_3 T_32*.  Analogously, *Pr(D = 2) = M_1 T_12 + M_2 T_22 + M_3 T_32*.  Now you can easily write the log-likelihood of observing D_1 and D_2 particles at locations 1 and 2.  The code might look like this:

```
loglik <- function(M) {
   if(M[1] < 0 | M[1] > 1)
      return(NA)
   if(M[2] < 0 | M[2] > 1)
      return(NA)
   M3 <- 1 - M[1] - M[2]
   if(M3 < 0 | M3 > 1)
      return(NA)
   D[1]*log(T[1,1]*M[1] + T[2,1]*M[2] + T[3,1]*M3) +
       D[2]*log(T[1,2]*M[1] + T[2,2]*M[2] + T[3,2]*M3)
}
T <- matrix(c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.9,0.8,0.7), 3, 2)
D <- c(100,200)
library(maxLik)
m <- maxLik(loglik, start=c(0.4,0.4), method="BFGS")
summary(m)
```

I get the answer *(0, 0.2, 0.8)* when I estimate it but standard errors are very large.

As I told, I have never done it so I don't know it it makes sense.

Comment: It looks like a reasonable solution to me, and indeed, I get reasonable answers when I put in a slightly larger (6x5) transit matrix. The only problem is that the answer it returns varies depending on the initial value. Presumably this means that there are multiple maxima to the equation (or minima)??

Comment: I suspect so.  Does the algorithm converge?  I am not quite certain what do BFGS convergence messages mean but NR methods I understand well (but that is based on 2nd order derivatives...)  Try using a global optimizer (SANN in maxLik package), or a separate package like rgenoud.  Try also some Monte-Carlo experiments where you trow particles in sea and check what do you get if you reverse compute the original distribution.

Comment: I am also afraid that if you try to estimate 1315 parameters based on 114 observations you are asking for a trouble...

Comment: Yes, the algorithm does converge, though if I ask for the summary it gives me the following error: "Error in eigen(hess, symmetric = TRUE, only.values = TRUE) :   infinite or missing values in 'x'".    I've tried doing as you said - simulating the coastal data from a known at-sea distribution, but again, the answer varies. I can try with a Monte-Carlo next!

Comment: I actually have thousands of observations on the coast, just 114 locations where those particles end up.

Comment: About the error message--thanks for reporting.  I should fix it.  Does it happen on the actual or test data?  Can you send me a piece of code?  (you can find my e-mail in the maxLik page at cran).